# MySQL Выборка данных по условию

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, не получается составить корректный запрос. Есть две таблицы 
`author` и `book` у обеих есть поле `id_author`. Мне требуется сделать выборку таких `id_author` которые есть в таблице `author` но отсутствуют в таблице `book`.

Использую сейчас не очень корректный запрос и не пойму даже почему он работает неправильно:

```
SELECT `author`.`id_author` FROM book, author WHERE `book`.`id_author` <> `author`.`id_author`
```

Данный код выводит не только все значения но ещё и дублирует их (В начале вывел из одной таблицы потом из второй)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> требуется сделать выборку таких id_author которые есть в таблице author но отсутствуют в таблице book.

```
SELECT a.id_author 
FROM author a
LEFT JOIN book b ON a.id_author = b.id_author
WHERE b.id_author IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from author a
where a.id_author not in (select id_author from book)
```